# svn updating checkout with new files before commit results to errors

Tags: svn

I have `checkout` my project to a folder so i can commit changes to it and then `update` them on the web server via

```
svn up
```

command

now when i want to move folderA from my local web server to `checkout` folder and commit changes i get the following error:

```
Commit failed (details follow): Directory '[directory]folderA/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing
```

know i get this error because .svn file is missing after pasting new files so how can i solve it except adding updated files one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think on UNIX simple `cp -R fromdir/folderA/* todir/folderA` will do the trick.

On Windows you can use a tool such as [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) that will allow you to 'deep copy' directory trees without overwriting your .svn .